# Elasticsearch Rest Client - ConnectionClosedException when calling performRequestAsync

Tags: java, apache, http, elasticsearch, nio

I'm having a problem on HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.

I'm using [elasticsearch Java Rest Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_example_requests.html) and I'm always getting a `ConnectionClosedException` (see below) when I call the `performRequestAsync`:

```
    // variables (all with valid format):
    // endpoint is just a List<String> with "14655/_search"

    // params is just a Map<String, String> with
    //   "pretty", "true"
    //   "search_type", "query_then_fetch"

    // entity is just a HttpEntity entity with the Json body request

    final int numRequests = endpoints.size();
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numRequests);
    try (Timer.Context ctx = this.requestTimer.time()) {
        for (final String endpoint : endpoints) {
            // ERROR hapens here:
            restClient.performRequestAsync("GET", endpoint, params, entity,
                    new ResponseListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(final Response response) {
                            if (response != null) {
                                responses.add(response);
                                latch.countDown();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(final Exception exception) {
                            latch.countDown();

                            logger.error("could not get search results for....",exception);
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

Exception here:

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:341)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:263)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:116)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:339)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:317)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:278)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:590)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't know what is the real cause for the connection close. The exact same request works well in [kopf](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf) and returns valid search results.
Plus, I don't call any `restClient.close()` or anything similar.

Any ideas where the problem might be? 
Is the end of the input the cause to get a closed connection state (according to `org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(conn)`)? If yes, what input is that?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I suspect the problem is related to Tomcat's `HttpClient`, because this code works correctly in an integration test (that is, returns results)... But it does not work (get the same `ConnectionClosedException`) when I make a REST request through a tomcat deployed "interface"

Any lights on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was the port was wrong. For REST requests the port should be 9200 (and not 9300 like it was configured). [More info on elasticsearch ports.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html)

I wish elasticsearch could make a more explicit error log or a hint like "are you connecting with the right port?" for when one tries to access the 9300 port with anything other than the built-in clients.